# Copy multiple rows from multiple workbooks to one master workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm new to VBA and are trying to copy multiple rows from multiple workbooks to one master workbook.
All workbooks have the same header and same number of colums but some have more rows. I would like a total of 6 workbooks (one worksheet per book) to be combined in the master workbook in one single worksheet, below eachother.

Header: Row 1, Column A through M
I would like to fill workbook "Daily trend 2013_MASTER_AR.xlsx" D4 through L4 all the way to D51 trough L51 to the master workbook "Daily trend 2013_MASTER.xlsx in cells E2:M2 and all the way down. Further on I'd like to do the same with the remaning 5 workbooks and the data in D4:L4 all the way down to row 81.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RDBMerge.

RDBMerge is a user friendly way to Merge Data from Multiple Excel Workbooks,
csv and xml files into a Summary Workbook.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/merge.htm