# VBA Array to copy multiple CSVs to one template workbook

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, copy-paste

Disclaimer - I used to write macros a lot, but it's a perishable skill. 5 years takes it toll.

The basic concept is this:

1. I have a template workbook, with up to 30 tabs, that all have indeterminate rows and columns (i.e. It's not always A7:J30 - one tab might have 3 columns, the next 34 columns. Rows are also indeterminate.).
2. Currently, someone is copy/pasting 30 separate CSVs into this one templated workbook.
3. This templated workbook is read by another program to populate data. Row 6 of each template sheet is where the other program looks for headers (i.e. I might copy a CSV's data from A2:G1000, but it would need to paste in A7:G1005 of the template target workbook).
4. All of the CSVs are stored in the same directory. We can copy/paste a Template workbook into that directory, run a macro, and be done.

What I've done so far:

```
Sub V1BruteForceCopy()
'
'This code lives in ImportTemplate.XLSM, and is run from the same
'
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\deposits.csv") 'Open deposits.CSV in same directory
Range("A2:G1000000").Copy                            'Very inflexible copy job - ugly.
Windows("ImportTemplate.xlsm").Activate              'hate to Activate, but can't get it to work without it.
Sheets("depositbatches").Range("A7").Select          'must call each Sheet in the code, instead of declare variable
ActiveSheet.Paste                                    'don't like Activate, but Sheets("depositbatches").Range("A7").Paste throws an error.
End Sub                                              'to add a new CSV and a new Sheet to copy to, I have to copy a whole new block of code and then overwrite Sheets("name") and Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkook.Path & "\name.csv") every time.
```

---

Other things I've tried:

```
Sub rangecopy_001()

Dim ImpTemp As Workbook     'Reserved for ImportTemplate
Dim CSVdeposits As Workbook 'Reserved for deposits.CSV 
Dim shDeposits As Worksheet 'Deposits worksheet inside ImportTemplate
Dim lRow As Long            'variable for last row
Dim lCol As Long            'variable for last column
Dim test As Range           'variable for copy/paste range

Set ImpTemp = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ImportTemplate_CSV.xlsm") 'Open DWImportTemplate
Set CSVdeposits = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\deposits.csv") 'Open deposits.CSV
Set shDeposits = ImpTemp.Sheets("depositbatches") 'Declare that shDeposits is a ImportTemplate sheet
With CSVdeposits 'copy out of deposits.CSV and paste into ImportTemplate deposits sheet

'find last row - makes this dynamic
lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

'find last column - makes this dynamic
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

test = CSVdeposits.Sheet(1).Range("A2:" & Cells(lRow, lCol))  'error code 438 - Object doesn't support method
DW.shDeposits.Range("A7") = test                              


End With


End Sub
```

This makes the copy range dynamic, but I'm still getting an object error when I try to select the range. I got this method from ([Copy from one workbook and paste into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351832/copy-from-one-workbook-and-paste-into-another#19352099)) but it's too simple. Plus, if I want to add another 20 tabs, I have to copy/paste this code block another 20 times and change the variables each time.

---

I found this ([Copy multiple rows from multiple workbooks to one master workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243576/copy-multiple-rows-from-multiple-workbooks-to-one-master-workbook)), but Ron DeBruin's thing won't work because we have to move everything down to Row 6, plus we can't count on the headers of the CSVs working properly.

---

I like the last answer here ([Dynamic range of data to paste into another sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198397/dynamic-range-of-data-to-paste-into-another-sheet)) but I can't seem to make it work for a single workbook target from other workbooks.

---

I want to use an array, or set of arrays to declare my worksheets, but I don't know how to iterate over two arrays at one time that are string-based. I'm thinking something like this, but I'm not done:

```
Sub ArrayCopyV1()
'
'This code lives in Template.XLSM and is run from the same. Copy this book to the directory you wish to copy from.
'
'
Dim ArraySheets As Variant   'an array with all Sheet names. Should have the same number of args as ArrayCSVs array.
Dim ArrayCSVs As Variant     'an array with all CSV names Should have the same number of args as ArraySheets array.
Dim template As Worksheet    'variable for template worksheet inside 
Template workbook
Dim CSV As Workbook          'variable for CSV workbook
Dim i As Integer             'variable i to be used in FOR loop counter
Dim lcol as Integer
Dim lrow as Integer

ArraySheets = Array("depositbatches", "otherSheet1", "OtherSheet2")
ArrayCSVs = Array("\deposits.csv", "other1.csv", "Other2.csv")

For i = LBound(ArraySheets) To UBound(ArraySheets)
Set CSV = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & ArrayCSVs(i))
Set template = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & ArraySheets(i))

    With CSV 'copy out of deposits.CSV and paste into DWImportTemplate deposits sheet

    'find last row - makes this dynamic
    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

    'find last column - makes this dynamic
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    test = CSV.Sheet(1).Range("A2:" & Cells(lRow, lCol))
    template.Range("A7") = test


    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the CSV data a contiguous block with no blank rows/columns? I would create a two-column table on a sheet in your xlsm, with one column for the file name and another for the destination sheet.  Then loop over that table row by row and open/copy/paste/close as you go.

Comment: Love this idea Tim! I will run it by the team to make sure an extra tab won't mess up other processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub CopyAll()
    Dim rw As Range, wb As Workbook
    'read over your file<>sheet table
    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Range("A2:B30").Rows
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rw.Cells(1).Value) '<< csv file name 
        With wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            'skip headers (relies on contiguous data)
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy _
                 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(rw.Cells(2).Value).Range("A7") '<< sheet name to paste into
        End With
        wb.Close False
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Clarification: when you say that it relies on contiguous data, is that just contiguous in Column A or in all columns? In general, I don't think it's safe to assume that ALL columns are contiguous.

Comment: If you select A1 on the sheet and press Ctrl+A (select all) does it select the full set of data?  Should be fine as long as the data doesn't contain blank rows or columns.

Comment: If that's a problem then consider using `wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange` instead.

Comment: Confirmed that we can do contiguous data. Your method is a good test. Also, tested it and there is ONE minor error:
    Set wb = Workbook
should be
    Set wb = Workbooks. Found this by using Option Explicit for the module. Otherwise, it was throwing a 424 Object Required code and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: OK - glad to see you figured it out.  Fixed the typo in the code.

Comment: Tim, I am running into a problem with Excel opening the CSVs and converting data wrong. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735928/5725420. What is the difference between your `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rw.Cells(1).Value)` and his `Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & rw.Cells(1).Value) For Input As wb` ? I can't get the latter to actually do anything - it just ends the sub without any action.

Comment: If you're having conversion errors then try using Data >> From Text and stepping through the options in that dialog: record a macro while doing that and it will give you a starting point.